# Listing values from a nested dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary

For a school assignment I need to list and sort values from a nested dictionary. Here's the dictionary:

```
dict = {"jan": [-2.9, 220.3], "feb": [-2, 202.6], "mar": [0.1, 129.5], 
"apr": [4.6, 114.5], "may": [9.4, 106.8], "jun": [14, 40.1], 
"jul": [16.2, 25.6], "aug": [15.5, 23.8], "sep": [11.8, 91.7], 
"oct": [6.8, 103.1],"nov": [2.6, 152.1], "dec": [-0.4, 241.3]}
```

I want the sorted list to look something like this:

```
-2.9, -2, 0.4, 0.1, 2.6, 4.6, etc.
```

I tried:

```
print(sorted(dict.values()))
```

but got this instead:

```
[[-2.9, 220.3], [-2, 202.6], [-0.4, 241.3], [0.1, 129.5], [2.6, 152.1], etc.
```

So, is there a way to list one value without the other pair?

Comment: You need to flatten those and then sort

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

Just u need to make a little tweak in you code. Because you just want to sort based on `0th index` value in `dict.values()`

**UPDATE :**

```
print(sorted(dict.values()))
```

**TO :**

```
print(sorted(i[0] for i in dict.values()))
```